# datagridview & mysql updating error

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I am using below code to update mysql view through datagridview

```
For Each row1 As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView2.Rows

                            If Not row1.IsNewRow Then
                                DataGridView2.CurrentCell = DataGridView2(0, ii)


                                    DataGridView2(2, ii).Value = intCaja


                                ii = ii + 1

                            End If

                            'Application.DoEvents()
                            DataGridView2.EndEdit()
                            da1.Update(ds1, "data")
                        Next
```

This code working very well, except that it updates all records except the last record only, although I see it updated in the datagridview

I have tried to refresh the datagrid or use it's update method, without any luck

Comment: Actually I don't understand what us the meaning of that I ask question and trying to have an answer, what ever it's easy for you or not, and find  that you are don't like the Qs or think it's very easy to you, you minus it without any try to help.

Comment: If you don't like to help so please say it's only for professionals, beginners are not welcome, so we will leave this community forever

Comment: For you that you downgraded this Q as not useful, I tried on this for a several hours on google without any luck, and didn't say it's easy to ask here instead of searching or trying. also I have pasted only a few lines of the code, which includes huge lines

Answer (score 0):

I'll add my answer here just for the people that may stuck with this easy issue like me yesterday, although that I didn't receive any positive feedback form this community.

Just be sure to add below line before `datagridview2.endedit()` method

```
DataGridView2.CurrentCell = Nothing
```

Thanks for no help from stackoverflow, and thanks for that person that he was happy to downgrade this Q